# How to free an array stored in heap returned from C++ DLL in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, heap-memory, marshalling

I have a C++ DLL that reads a buffer and returns its content as a char array along with its size.

And I have a C# code that imports the DLL and it can read the array content and size created from C++, but it is causing a memory leak.

I am creating a dynamic array in heap from the C++ side and I know that after using `new char[]` I should use `delete[]` to [free the array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/arrays-cpp?view=msvc-170#heap-declarations), but in this case I don't know how or where to put it or if it is possible to do it from C# side.

Here is my c++ side code. I tried putting only the important parts.

`mystream.h`

```
class MyStream {
public:
    char* data;
    ULONG size;
};

MyStream getStream(){
    MyStream result;
    result.size = getBufferSize(); // Gets the buffer size. The size is not constant so I cannot store the array in stack
    result.data = new char[result.size]; // Creates a new char array, now knowing its size
    ReadBuffer(result.data, result.size) // Reads a buffer and result.data now has the buffer content. Someting like this: ['a','b','c','d','e',...]
    return result;
};
```

`c++ export`

```
#include "mystream.h"

MyStream getMyStream()
{
    MyStream myStream = getStream();
    return myStream;

    // here if I use delete[] myStream.data it will take no effect
}
```

`DLL export`

```
extern "C"
{
    DLLExport MyStream getMyStream();
}
```

And here is my c# side code.

```
public struct MyStream
{
    public IntPtr Data;
    public int Size;
}

[DllImport("my-stream")]
public static extern MyStream getMyStream();


public void ReadUsingTheDLL()
{
    MyStream myStream = getMyStream();
    byte[] byteStreamArray = new byte[myStream.Size]; // I can read the array size, all good
    Marshal.Copy(myStream.Data, byteStreamArray, 0, myStream.Size); // I can read the array content in byteStreamArray, all good


    // How do I free the memory from myStream.Data? since I am no longer using it
}
```

Comment: You can't. Either make a separate `free` function export in C++ that you can call from C#, or better: pass in the buffer from C# in the first place.

Comment: Or write your DLL as managed CLI compliant C++ (yeah... i know; ugh) and just let it manage the garbage collection.